# Need to Seriazlize List<object>, but FXCop complains "Do not expose generic lists"

Tags: list, serialization, generics, fxcop

I have an object that I need to serialize. The object contains several properties, including a List. FXCop is complaining that I should not expose generic lists, and I get that, however, due to the fact that I can't specify an interface based property on an object that I want serialized I'm not sure where to turn next.

Any thoughts?

BTW, I'm using XMLSerialization, but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took FxCop's suggestion and wrapped my list in a Collection. This blew some of my code out of the water, but a after a few adjustments I was up and running again.

Here's some code showing before and after:

Before:

```
   public class PersistentDataView
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        private List<object> Inputs { get; set;}
    }
```

After:

```
    public class PersistentDataView
    {
        private List<object> _inputs;

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Collection<object> Inputs
        {
            get
            {
                if (_inputs == null)
                    _inputs = new List<object>();

                //Wrap the private field into a collection.
                return new Collection<object>(_inputs);
            }
        }
  }
```